# concatenate variables

Tags: batch-file

I need to do a .bat for DOS that do the following:

```
set ROOT = c:\programas\
set SRC_ROOT = (I want to put the ROOT Here)System\Source
```

so after defining ROOT I want to have SRC_ROOT = c:\programas\System\Source

How can I do that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
set ROOT=c:\programs 
set SRC_ROOT=%ROOT%\System\Source
```

Answer (score 16):

Note that if strings has spaces then quotation marks are needed at definition and must be chopped while concatenating:

```
rem The retail files set
set FILES_SET="(*.exe *.dll"

rem The debug extras files set
set DEBUG_EXTRA=" *.pdb"

rem Build the DEBUG set without any
set FILES_SET=%FILES_SET:~1,-1%%DEBUG_EXTRA:~1,-1%

rem Append the closing bracket
set FILES_SET=%FILES_SET%)

echo %FILES_SET%
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 12):

If you need to concatenate paths with quotes, you can use `=` to replace quotes in a variable. This does not require you to know if the path already contains quotes or not. If there are no quotes, nothing is changed.

```
@echo off
rem Paths to combine
set DIRECTORY="C:\Directory with spaces"
set FILENAME="sub directory\filename.txt"

rem Combine two paths
set COMBINED="%DIRECTORY:"=%\%FILENAME:"=%"
echo %COMBINED%

rem This is just to illustrate how the = operator works
set DIR_WITHOUT_QUOTES=%DIRECTORY:"=%
echo %DIR_WITHOUT_QUOTES%
```

Comment: This fails miserably if the string contains any characters that the command processor interprets, which is probably why the string was quoted in the first place.

Comment: @FreonSandoz What are those characters? Are they allowed in paths?