# How to concatenate local variables which contain spaces

Tags: batch-file

I am trying Hertzel Guinness' method from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856573/concatenate-variables/45927406?noredirect=1#comment78814440_45927406). Perhaps I am misunderstanding it but I cannot seem to get it to work. Windows7 *Version 6.1.7601*.

My code is:

```
set pathA ="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
set pathB ="Libraries\Documents"
set pathA=%pathA:~1,-1%%pathB:~1,-1%
%pathA%
```

The output displays:

> ..Desktop\BatchFiles>~1,-1%pathB:~1,-1 '~1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG[Space]" to a value of "[Space]N" so you are not setting `path*`

Comment: A file path is not a command either. If you want to see the content of %pathA%, then use `Echo %pathA%` or `Set pathA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to not include something than to do so and subsequently remove it.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "pathA=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
Set "pathB=Libraries\Documents"
Set "pathA=%pathA%%pathB%"
Echo "%pathA%"
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had an inkling to try that but didn't think that the = operator would work inside the " " .  That worked.